# If a column value does not have a certain number of occurances in a dataframe, how to duplicate rows at random until that count is met?

Tags: pandas

Say that this is what my dataframe looks like

```
A   B
0   1   5
1   4   2
2   3   5
3   3   3
4   3   2
5   2   0
6   4   5
7   2   3
8   4   1
9   5   1
```

I want every unique value in Column B to occur at least 3 times. So none of the rows with a B value of 5 are duplicated. The row with a column B value of 0 are duplicated twice. And the rest have one of their two rows duplicated at random.

Here is an example desired output

```
A   B
0   1   5
1   4   2
2   3   5
3   3   3
4   3   2
5   2   0
6   4   5
7   2   3
8   4   1
9   5   1
10  4   2
11  2   3
12  2   0
13  2   0
14  4   1
```

Edit:
The row chosen to be duplicated should be selected at random

Comment: how many unique values in B there are in original dataframe?

Comment: In the original, 50, with 100k datapoints. I just created this example for minimal

Comment: so, each fill-row is a random row or one random row to fill for each `B` group?

Comment: One whole random row fill, until each unique value in column B has the specified number of occurrences.

Comment: let say on real dataset, you want repeat 5 time instead of 3. There is a group of `B` has only 2 rows, so you need to create 3 more rows for it. For this 3 row, you want to use the same random row for all or on each you want to pick random row again?

Comment: pick a random row again each time from the original 2 rows. I am wondering if this may increase by the computational complexity by a lot.

Comment: Perhaps if the number of current rows is less than half of the number of desired frequency, all the rows can by duplicated. And then use random selection each time for the rest of the fill.

Comment: It is doable, but it definitely a hit to performance to random pick for each row. I have to go now. It would take me a while before I am back to the computer. When I am back, I will revise the answer. If you need it now, I guess you may ask @ansev. I am sure he is able to help you out.

Comment: I think my original desire for a solution with each duplicate selected randomly may be too computationally expensive, so I created a new question where all the rows are just duplicated once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142342/if-a-column-value-does-not-have-a-certain-number-of-occurances-in-a-dataframe-h

Comment: @SantoshGupta7: as I promised, I revised my solution to pick random rows for each group and each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To random pick rows, I would use groupby `apply` with `sample` on each group. `x` of lambda is each group of `B`, so I use `reapeat - x.shape[0]` to find number of rows need to create. There may be some cases group `B` already has more rows than `3`, so I use `np.clip` to force negative values to `0`. Sample on `0` row is the same as ignore it. Finally, reset_index and `append` back to `df`

```
repeats = 3
df1 = (df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=np.clip(repeats-x.shape[0], 0, np.inf)
                                                    .astype(int), replace=True))
                      .reset_index(drop=True))

df_final = df.append(df1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[43]:
    A  B
0   1  5
1   4  2
2   3  5
3   3  3
4   3  2
5   2  0
6   4  5
7   2  3
8   4  1
9   5  1
10  2  0
11  2  0
12  5  1
13  4  2
14  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why the ints are converted to floats?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7: ah, `reindex` creates `NaN`. When `NaN` exists, the column is forced to convert to dtype `float`. If you need `int`, just cast it after `ffill` as `.astype(int)`

Comment: Would this method also work if column A were string values?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7: it definitely will. It will forward-fill whatever values of previous row after `reindex`. However, in that case, you only cast back `int` for non-string columns.

Comment: this for a larger data frame is slow.
that is, if there is a reduced number of unique values ​​of B it works well, but if the number of unique values ​​of B is larger, many groups will be created and the loop will become very slow

Comment: This method seems to copy the same value over and over for the repeats, instead of picking rows with the column b value at random

Comment: @SantoshGupta7: ah, you want to get random. I thought you mean just pick what every row. Therefore, I chose the last row to repeat.

Comment: @ansev: I agree that if dataset have a big set of different values on `B`. This will be slow down :). However, now the true issue is that OP wants a random pick row, so both my solution and yours need to change.

Comment: so random values ​​are chosen from column B or from column A?

Comment: The whole row should be duplicated, so B/A