# If a column value does not have a certain number of occurances in a dataframe, how to duplicate all rows with that column value?

Tags: pandas

Say this my dataframe

```
    A   B
0   a   5
1   b   2
2   d   5
3   g   3
4   m   2
5   c   0
6   u   5
7   p   3
8   q   1
9   z   1
```

If the number of a particular value in column B does not have a particular occurrence count, I want to duplicate all rows which have that particular value for B.

For the df above, say this particular value is 3. If a value for Column B is less than three, than all rows with that column value are duplicated. So rows with column value 0, 1, and 2 are duplicated, but rows with column b value of 5 are not.

Desired result:

```
    A   B
0   a   5
1   b   2
2   d   5
3   g   3
4   m   2
5   c   0
6   u   5
7   p   3
8   q   1
9   z   1
10   b   2
11   m   2
12   g   3
13   p   3
14   c   0
15   c   0
```

Comment: So what is important is the number of occurrences of the value or the value itself?

Comment: I am creating training data for a machine learning model. The dataset is unbalanced; there are many datapoints for 1 class, but very few for another, so I need to augment the data for the datapoints that have few samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my approach**

```
n=3 #threshold
df2 = (df.assign(columns = df.groupby('B').cumcount())
         .pivot_table(columns = 'columns',
                      index = 'B',
                      values = 'A',
                      aggfunc = 'first')

      )
r = max(n,len(df2.columns))
df2 = df2.reindex(columns = range(r))

notNaN_count = df2.count(axis=1)
m_ffill = notNaN_count.mul(2).lt(n)
repeats = notNaN_count.lt(n).mul(~m_ffill).add(1)


new_df = (df2.ffill(axis = 1)
             .where(m_ffill,df2)
             .reindex(index = df2.index.repeat(repeats))
             .stack()
             .rename('A')
             .reset_index()
             .loc[:,df.columns]
         )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
    A  B
0   c  0
1   c  0
2   c  0
3   q  1
4   z  1
5   q  1
6   z  1
7   b  2
8   m  2
9   b  2
10  m  2
11  g  3
12  p  3
13  g  3
14  p  3
15  a  5
16  d  5
17  u  5
```

---

if instead of duplicating we want to multiply by a factor `d`,
we must make the following modifications:

```
n = 3
d = 2

m_ffill = notNaN_count.mul(d).lt(n)
repeats = notNaN_count.lt(n).mul(~m_ffill).mul(d).clip(lower = 1)
```

**EDIT**

```
n=3 #threshold
d = 2
values = df.columns.difference(['B'])
df2 = (df.assign(columns = df.groupby('B').cumcount())
         .pivot_table(columns = 'columns',
                      index = 'B',
                      values = values,
                      aggfunc = 'first'))

r = max(n,len(df2.columns.get_level_values('columns').unique()))
df2 = df2.reindex(columns = range(r),level = 'columns')


notNaN_count = df2.count(axis=1).div(len(values))
m_ffill = notNaN_count.mul(d).lt(n)
repeats = notNaN_count.lt(n).mul(~m_ffill).mul(d).clip(lower = 1)


new_df = (df2.T
             .groupby(level=0)
             .ffill()
             .T
             .where(m_ffill,df2)
             .reindex(index = df2.index.repeat(repeats))
             .stack()
             .reset_index()
             .loc[:,df.columns]
         )
```

Comment: How would we alter it if there's more than one column for the other values. Like Column A and something else

Comment: check section EDIT

Comment: When I tried on my data, I get `ValueError: Function does not reduce`. I'm stuck on what's going wrong. `dfshuff.assign(columns = dfshuff.groupby('Cat_ID').cumcount())` seems to work fine. So the issue is occurring somewhere with the pivot table : `.pivot_table(columns = 'columns'. . . `.